# Understanding this implementation of A-star algorithm in Python

Tags: python, path-finding, a-star

I am new to Python. I have this Code with me
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577519-a-star-shortest-path-algorithm/history/1/

its the A star algorithm code. I wanted to know how exactly is it generating the obstacles.
Basically I have a black and white image. My task is to reach the end point from the start point avoiding the white spaces.
Please help me
Thank you!

Comment: What's the question? What have you tried yet?

Comment: I have an image. I have its pixels. All I want to do is find the path avoiding white region. How do you suggest I go about?

Comment: I'd use simple BFS in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The path-finding algorithm in function `pathFind()` is well-commented and decomposed. If there's something specific confusing you, tell us what it is. The important lines are after `# generate moves (child nodes) in all possible directions`, which admittedly is dense code and not very OO.

I suggest you reduce the parameters (m,n) to a 4x5 or 5x6 then step through its execution, either with pdb debugger (single-step or set breakpoints at key points), or hacking in as many print statements as you need:

```
# map matrix
n = 30 # horizontal size
m = 30 # vertical size
```

First try giving it your own custom maps to get a feel for how it works (modify the `# fillout the map matrix...` lines). Then run it interactively in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was foing the correct thing, but I was using a different image :P

Comment: I don't understand, did you solve your question? or not?